# Where can I find some beautiful iPhone buttons?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

Don't need image background, just good-looking color is enough.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask this question on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jeff LaMarche has some very iOS-looking and simple-to-use [programmatic gradient buttons here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/improved-gradient-buttons.html).

You just need to add a .h and .m file to your project and you are good to go.

[image: iPhone gradient buttons]

Comment: Since I am linking to the man's blog I might as well also recommend his book if you are a beginning iOS programmer:  http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-iPhone-Development-Exploring-iOS/dp/143023024X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1306828401&sr=8-1

Answer (score 2):

http://www.youthedesigner.com/2010/03/10/29-sexy-iphone-app-designs/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/09/iphone-app-design-trends/

These may not be of any use but check them out. There are some really well designed apps and u'll get a good idea of what colours work. Your question is slightly vague to provide an exact answer IMO.

You can get the RBB values of the colours using a number of tools.

Answer (score 2):

Check this

[Fun With UIButtons and Core Animation Layers](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/)

[image]