# IOS - Objective C - Merging Bunch of Images in one Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I have bunch of images of human face's different parts. now i want to make a human face in single image with using of those bunch of images and make a perfect human face. for that i did searched for that but cant find any proper solution. so please guide me for that.

Comment: can you show us those sample images? are they in same shape of same size?

Comment: No, images in different size of different shape.

Comment: http://www.massagetoday.com/content/images/pain_guide_47141_1_1_3929.gif
In this image 1 to 10 numbers images are bunch of images and want to make single image from those images.

Comment: ok, so if you click on 1, you will show info of 1... right? this is what you wanna do??

Comment: yes, when i click on any parts...i want select that parts with different colour.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190073/custom-uibutton-shape-without-using-an-image). Check this --> [this will help for sure](http://www.planet1107.net/blog/custom-shape-uibutton-tutorial/)

Comment: ok...i will check it out..thanks

Comment: Do you want all these part selectable...?

Comment: Do you have 10 different images for 10 parts or you have one single  image?

Comment: please change the title of your quesiton. It is quite confusing and is not what it means.

Comment: @RahulMishra Yes i want all these parts selectable...and i have 10 different images for 10 parts.

Comment: Okay....You want to make all these parts fixed or you allow user to change their position?  What is the problem in mannually making the shape

Comment: No..these parts are fixed not movable. i dont know how to manually make the shape.

Comment: just arrange them....Use autolayout for it